# Maximum size of unmanaged object in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Quick question: what is the maximum size of an unmanaged object that C# can handle? I think I may have found my way around my 64-bit array problem, by making calls to a C++ dll, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: Even if it's possible to deal with objects that gigantic, it's unlikely going to be pleasant.  Consider breaking it up into multiple smaller objects to make it easier to deal with.

Comment: Big arrays are supported on .NET 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's limited, in the end, by `VirtualAlloc`, and it depends how you use the memory, and which OS you're running. Accessing it via C#/.NET doesn't really change this. The Windows Internals book has [a Testlimit[64] application which explores these limits](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx). Read the linked post and try out the application for a complete answer.